# Run Angular 2 project without Node/NPM

Tags: angular

Is there a way to run the Angular 2 startup project https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/README.md without having to run NPM or Node? I don't mind using NPM to download the packages, but I don't want to have to run the server to run the project. Is there a way to separate the two?

I have spent about an hour looking for a reasonable answer and seem to come up short. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The quickstart can be served by apache without node's help as any html/js  files. npm install then npm run tsc will install dependencies and compiles ts without starting a server.

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely need to run `npm install` to download the dependencies. As for doing it without running the server, the application makes numerous XHR calls to be able to function and your browser might need special setup to do this. ie. In Chrome for OSX you'll need to launch Chrome through the terminal like this `open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files`. You'll also need to use the typescript compiler by running it in in watch mode (using `npm run tsc:w`) or by invoking it manually by running `tsc` everytime you want to compile your changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WebStorm you don't need a server. Just right click index.html and select "Run index.html". It will then start its internal web server and load the app.

Other IDEs might also support this.

Comment: I am using Idea, and it does not work outside of me running npm start